# How to set multiple prefixes or make prefix case insensitive in discord.py library?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm creating a discord bot in python using discord.py library.
My problem is that I can't have prefix case insensitive.
Is there any way to make it case insensitive or have multiple prefixes?

I have tried to set the prefix to "" and add the prefix to the commands
but this will make the bot processing every single message!
Is there any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Patrick Haugh's answer is most likely what you're looking for, however I would personally use a method that you could potentially use to have custom prefixes for multiple guilds.

```
with open('prefix.json', 'r') as f:
    prefixList = json.load(f)

async def getPrefix(bot, message):
    return prefixList.get(str(message.guild.id), "Enter a default prefix here")
```

This code should work if you create a JSON database in the same directory for prefixes and store them with the guild ID as key for each prefix.

You can then call this function when you are defining the prefix for the bot. 
Happy coding!

Answer (score 7):

yea I actually found a way to do so by tampering with code

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=["hi ","Hi "])
```

make a list of prefix that you wanna use

Answer (score 3):

You can pass an iterable of strings to have multiple prefixes, or a function that takes a `Bot` and a `Message`:

```
bot = Bot(('ab', 'Ab', aB', 'AB'))
```

or

```
def check(bot, message):
    return message.content[:2].lower() == 'ab'

bot = Bot(check)
```

See [the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command_prefix) for more details